# Why doesn't the commands to build openBR run?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, openbr

When I run the commands specified in OpenBR page to build the library, I am getting the following error. Its coming when I execute the sub module update command.

[image]

Is it because the the repository is not available in that location? If that's not the case, why is it not running?

Answer (score 0):

(At first I think it should be a comment but I cant). 
I have the same issue like you when I install it. I believe the problem here is the link to repos of doc of openbr(it's not correct, maybe it's changed). You can continue with build process, this error dont have any effect in it and use the doc from official website. Good luck!